# How to reduce Cycles logging output?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, command-line

when rendering scenes on the farm, the created logfiles get huge. Is there a way to reduce cycles log output? --verbose didn't work for me...
Thx

Comment: Would it work have a script or something delete old log files after a render is completed successfully?

Comment: They get deleted after a time anyway. It's just that they take longer to load and contain thousands of lines of information logging every path trace. I would love just some basic information like rendertime, memory consumption, frame written successfully, error messages (texture not found) and stuff like that.

Comment: hm? That's precisely the information I get.. Where are these logs coming from? I assumed you were running a CLI render and piping stdout and stderr into a file.. Is there another way?

Comment: well, when I run: "blender -b myscene.blend -a" in the commandline I get this [logoutput](http://www.pasteall.org/56260) This is just for one frame and I skipped 100 lines or so, because I think you get the idea. Now imagine higher rendersettings (tracing tile 845 of 1940) and more than one frame.

Comment: Oh I see, you are rendering animations?

Comment: ah, sorry yes animations. Is the output different for a single frame??

Comment: No, but you only get one frame of it (so having information for every tile makes sense).

Comment: True. Anyway, a option for different loglevels would be awesome. Errors, warnings, information, detailed. Where the current status would be the detailed one I guess. Even for a still image you get a logfile with more than 1000 lines easily at the moment.