# Can i get render log from blender?

Tags: python, rendering, export

I am quite new to blender, for the task i need to export render logs from blender, but i couldn't find anything in docs regarding getting render logs. Is there any way to get render log, or even better export it to txt file.
Thank you.

Comment: Only by running Blender from the command line I believe. See the 4th comment from knekke here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23533/how-to-reduce-cycles-logging-output and also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43110/does-blender-keep-a-log-when-its-rendering might help.